# Updating state of sibling component ends up in infinite loop using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component `PlannerWrapper` that has the child components `PlannerChart` which returns an ApexChart instance and renders it to the DOM and another child component `PlannerTools` which takes some form inputs and updates the existing chart instance.

I want to update the chart always on change of a form input which somehow works but it doesn't use the latest changed data but instead the previous state. I think this is because I have the `props.setChartOptions(calculateOffer(values))` inside the stateHandler.

When I integrate `useEffect` to solve this I end up with an infinite loop right on page load... why and how to fix this?

```
// PlannerWrapper

const PlannerWrapper = () => {

    // Create option state for chart
    const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
        options: {
                ...
 
    return (
        <div className="wrapper w-6/6 h-full flex bg-dotted  bg-sx-white">
            <div className="left-wrapper w-3/6 h-full p-8 pr-0 flex flex-col justify-between">
                <div className="chart-wrapper w-full h-48p bg-sx-white-plain rounded-2xl shadow-sx-shadow">
                    <PlannerChart chartOptions={chartOptions}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <PlannerTools setChartOptions={setChartOptions}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
// PlannerTools

import {calculateOffer} from "./utils";

const PlannerTools = (props) => {

    const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
        if(prop === 'date') {
          return setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event });
        }
        setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });

        console.log('test')
        // Re-Run calculations
        props.setChartOptions(calculateOffer(values)) // <--- This should run once after the new state is available
    };
...
```

```
// PlannerTools with useEffect

const PlannerTools = (props) => {

..
    const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
        if(prop === 'date') {
          return setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event });
        }
        setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        props.setChartOptions(calculateOffer(values)) // <-- ends up in an infinite loop right on page load
    })
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `values` as a dependency of `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.setChartOptions(calculateOffer(values));
}, [values]);
```

to only run this effect when `values` is changed.

In the code without `useEffect`, `values` is bound to the previous data and not the latest data because `setState` in React is asynchronous.
That means `setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });` is not immediately update your `values`.

[Read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) (This link refers to `setState` in class component, but it should be the same for `useState` hook)